# Get Folder names into txt file in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write folder names into a txt file. So far I'm here;

```
string yol = Application.StartupPath + "\\isimler.txt";
System.IO.StreamWriter zzz = new System.IO.StreamWriter(yol);
string[] lines = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\test");
zzz.WriteLine(lines);
zzz.Close();
```

How can i write folder names to txt file?

Comment: Have you tried to use `Path.GetDirectoryName`, `FileInfo.Directory` etc. Try to use google before asking SO

Comment: I didn't try `Path.GetDirectoryName`, `FileInfo.Directory` etc. And also i tried google as the topic and also get folders into string etc. EZI thanks for lightning..I can list folder names in another place of code, what i want is write them to a txt file..

Comment: What is 2 minuses for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Directory.GetDirectories` to get all the folder name in specified directory, then traverse it and write to .txt file. 
The code snippet as following:

```
string yol =  "isimler.txt";
System.IO.StreamWriter zzz = new System.IO.StreamWriter(yol);
string[] lines = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\");
foreach(string name in lines)
    zzz.WriteLine(name);
zzz.Close();
```

Comment: and what about sub sub directories?

Comment: Recurse the sub directories which you got in **string[] lines**.

Comment: I asked it not why I don't know what to do, just to help to improve your question. But Since it is *accepted* already, forget it. People can live  with this dumb answer

Comment: Well sorry to break your dreams down EZI. Not that i didn't think about it, just didn't need it to ask. People can live with this dump answer, question is people care?